# Changing the pattern in setLineDash:count:phase: to an arc in ios core graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am drawing an ellipse

```
CGRect paperRect = self.bounds;
CGRect strokeRect = CGRectInset(paperRect, 5.0, 5.0);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, strokeRect);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I was hoping to change this to a jarred ellipse (see pic). In search for the best way to do this, I was wondering if there is a way to use

```
setLineDash:count:phase:
```

and pass an arc/ curve as the pattern instead of line? Or is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**
I tried the following, as suggested by Wain:

```
float a = strokeRect.size.width/2;
float b = strokeRect.size.height/2;

float x1,y1,x2,y2,k;
x1=CGRectGetMinX(strokeRect);
y1=CGRectGetMinY(strokeRect);
int maxAngle = 360;

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1, y1); 
for(int i=0;i<maxAngle;i+=30){

    float cX=cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(i));
    float sX=sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(i));
    k=1/(sqrt(pow((b*cX),2) + pow(a*sX,2)));
    x2=k*a*b*cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(i));
    y2=k*a*b*sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(i));

   CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, x1, y1, x2, y2, 20);
    x1=x2; // make x2 the new x1
    y1=y2;

}

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I can see some irregular drawings, but nothing to the extend that makes sense visually.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't 'pass a line' as the dash. The dash is a description of how the line is drawn.

You need to create a path (instead of the ellipse) which traces the 'jarred ellipse' shape (using `CGContextAddArcToPoint`) and then draw that.

The points are all on the edge of the ellipse, you can find them with the calculations described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151936/finding-points-on-ellipse). I haven't tried it but I guess the first tangent point could be the center point of the ellipse...

Comment: it is not always a circle, but more of an ellipse. I did explore finding points on the ellipse and adding arcs, and it goes to solving quadratic equations for iterating angles. I was hoping for a more straightforward solution if there was one. :)

Comment: @aVC: Nothing involving `setLineDash:count:phase:`.